# Set stacked bar chart display height to 100%

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am new to jasper reports and was trying to use the stacked barchart tool for one of my reports. Problem is in my research I haven't seen good documentation that illustrates how i could use percentages for the different stacks so that the values all add up to 100 percent in one bar serie for every category. Currently I am just trying to achieve that in my SQL queries by calculating the percentages in the query then setting the maximum property value of the bar to 100 which is not working well for me. Is there a way to get the percentages on the stacks just by passing the actual values of that the sql query returns rather than calculating percentages in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a bar chart for this?

This is exactly the scope where you would normally use the pie chart.

Anyway, you could just create a variable that sums up all the values from the different fields.

```
<variable name="XXX" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[{Sum of all the stuff}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

Comment: I am using a stacked bar since I have several categories of the data series and using a pie chart would result into me having a number of charts for each category. Also sorry am asking before I try this out, but just for better understanding, how does the variable that sums the totals of all help in having stacked columns that add up to 100%. Thanks